# CSS in HTML, and all this in python

Tags: python, html, css

There was a problem with importing css code into html code that is in python. I use python on a tablet (this just does not allow me to use additional text files) using "http.server”  and I don't know how to write down css rules. Can you help?

Here is the code:

`

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from http.server import HTTPServer
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  server_address = ('', 8000)
  httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
  try:
      httpd.serve_forever()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
      httpd.server_close()
class HttpGetHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        print( dir( self ) )
        self.wfile.write(s.css())
        self.wfile.write(s.encode())
s = """
<DOCTYPE!>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <title>Simple Site</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
"""
run(handler_class=HttpGetHandler)
```

`

I superficially looked at quite a large number of articles, but found nothing.